# What kind of pipe nipple to use on my well pitless adapter

Tags: water, pipe, underground

I am working on the water pipe that connects to the pitless adapter on my well casing.  There is a 1 in black pipe nipple that is screwed into the brass female thread of the pitless adapter.  I have a threaded pvc coupling screwed on to the other end of the nipple.  The pipe nipple developed a hole in it and started leaking.  So, now it needs to be replaced.  I guess I could just extend the pvc and screw a plastic fitting directly in to the pitless adapter, but I am of the opinion that I still want a metal to metal connection at the pitless adapter.  I am considering a 1 in x 3 in or 1 in x 6 in brass nipple.  Those are not impossible to find but not easy either.  Any thoughts?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just recommend using brass fittings for all of that stuff.

- 1" brass close nipple
- 1" FPT x 1" Brab brass female insert adapter

[image]

If you can't find a female insert adapter, you can basically make one using a 1" female-female coupler + 1" male MPT x 1" Barb insert adapter.

Should look something like this (though don't forget to use stainless steel clamps on the pipe, which this guy hasn't put on yet):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Stainless steel, brass (I'd suggest surface-treating for free lead before use) would both be a better choice than black iron, which was a dielectric bad move on someone's part. Though I'd expect the pitless to be bronze rather than brass...

Shippable well parts are often easier to find on-line than locally, especially if they are out of the ordinary materials-wise. I've never seen stainless nipples in a store, but they can be had online easily enough.

If you are going to PVC threads, I'm not sure that a metal-to-metal connection at the pitless buys you anything, since the plastic threads can still snap 3 or 6 inches away and drop your whole string down the well. But I'm habituated to metal threads on a barbed adapter double-hose-clamped to 160 or 200 PSI polyethylene pipe going down-well, so that's mostly just fear of a system I've never used and some experience with PVC stress-cracking as it ages. I suppose its possible that a female-threaded plastic fitting might be a little more sturdy than a male-threaded one.